# How do I create a sieve script in dovecot that sends a vacation autoreply from the userdb, like LDAP?

Tags: dovecot, sieve

The sieve vacation described at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5230 allows a vacation message to be defined and sent by dovecot.

By default, the text of the vacation message is hardcoded in the sieve script.

How do I populate the text of the vacation message from an extra field from the dovecot userdb so that multiple users can share the same sieve script but still customise their vacation message in LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this all together, there are a number of steps that need to be done to make this work:

- You need to turn on the sieve_extprograms plugin:

```
  sieve_plugins = sieve_extprograms
```

- Then you need to enable vnd.dovecot.environment:

```
  sieve_global_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.environment
```

- Then you need to pull the extra fields you want out of the userdb, and those fields must be prefixed with **sieve_env_**, like this example for LDAP:

```
  user_attrs = mailMessageStore=home=%$,=sieve_env_mail_auto_reply_mode=%{ldap:mailAutoReplyMode},=sieve_env_mail_auto_reply_text=%{ldap:mailAutoReplyText}
```

- Then you need to add a requirement on “vnd.dovecot.environment” to the sieve script as per the example below.
- Then, to access the variables in the sieve script, you need to drop the "**sieve_env_**" part, and add the prefix "**env.vnd.dovecot.config.**". There are various docs floating around that reference the above variable without the leading “env.” - this must be there too.
- The resulting sieve looks like this:

```
require ["fileinto", "mailbox"];
require ["vacation", "variables"];
require ["vnd.dovecot.environment"];

# fileinto: for putting mail into a imap folder
# mailbox: for creating imap folder if not exists
#
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
    # move mail into folder Junk, create folder if not exists
    fileinto :create "Junk";
    stop;
}

if string :matches "${env.vnd.dovecot.config.mail_auto_reply_mode}" "reply" {
    if header :matches "subject" "*" {
        vacation :subject "AutoReply: ${1}"
            "${env.vnd.dovecot.config.mail_auto_reply_text}";
    }
}
```

- The output of sieve-test looks like this. The handle is weird, but I’m assuming there is method in the madness somehow:

```
sieve-test(root): Debug: sieve: Pigeonhole version 0.5.8 (b7b03ba2) initializing
sieve-test(root): Debug: sieve: include: sieve_global is not set; it is currently not possible to include `:global' scripts.
sieve-test(root): Debug: sieve: Sieve Extprograms plugin for Pigeonhole version 0.5.8 (b7b03ba2) loaded
debug: file storage: Using Sieve script path: /var/lib/dovecot-sieve/default.sieve.
debug: file script: Opened script `default' from `/var/lib/dovecot-sieve/default.sieve'.
debug: Script binary /var/lib/dovecot-sieve/default.svbin successfully loaded.
debug: binary save: not saving binary /var/lib/dovecot-sieve/default.svbin, because it is already stored.

Performed actions:

 * send vacation message:
    => seconds : 604800
    => subject : AutoReply: Test1
    => handle  : ${env.vnd.dovecot.config.mail_auto_reply_text}AutoReply: ${1}<default-from><NO-MIME>

START MESSAGE
I am truly away...
END MESSAGE

Implicit keep:

 * store message in folder: INBOX

sieve-test(root): Info: final result: success
```